# Breaking on string access from StringTable (resource)

Tags: ida, ghidra, x64dbg, pe-resources

If I have a resource like this:

```
STRINGTABLE
LANGUAGE LANG_ENGLISH, SUBLANG_ENGLISH_US
{
100,    "OK"
101,    "Warning"
102,    "Error"
103,    "Name"
104,    "Size"
}
```

1- How can I place a BP (conditional) to break when the string `102` is accessed (x64. I do not know which function is used to load the string)?

2- How could I detect this code in a disassembler such as Ghidra/IDA?

Answer (score 1):

1. you don't ... there's a slim chance to use a hardware breakpoint to trigger when the (mapped) resource string gets accessed, though.
2. you need to stake out what APIs get used which could be used to read the string(s). The first one to go to here would be [`LoadString`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-loadstringw) for obvious reasons. But it's possible that your target uses [`FindResource`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/libloaderapi/nf-libloaderapi-findresourcew) (or the corresponding `*Ex`-function), followed by `LoadResource`, `LockResource` etc.

So if I were you I'd look at the import table first. Check if either `LoadStringA` or `LoadStringW` exists and check all instances. The ID parameter for the resource ID should be pretty obvious.

Failing that I'd look for `GetProcAddress` and friends and whether that is used to get the function `LoadString` and call it.

Failing that I'd look for the other functions I mentioned above.

Failing that I'd investigate which internal functions inside `ntdll.dll` are used to implement resource handling and break on those, then investigate the call stack.

If all of the above fails I'd set a hardware breakpoint on the resource string itself in an attempt to catch the program accessing the string.

**NB:** in multilingual applications the resource ID would still matter and typically be identical across languages, but there's a chance the string you're after is in another (resource-only) DLL altogether. Such DLLs have no entry point or code and are purely mapped as data. This could be relevant if you come up empty-handed in all but the last approach ... because for the last approach you'll have to set the breakpoint on the right data.

Answer (score 0):

> 1- How can I place a BP (conditional) to break when the string 102 is
> accessed (x64. I do not know which function is used to load the
> string)?

First, it is necessary to find the right method used to load the string. The standard one is `LoadString` but, as **@0xC0000022L** mentioned, there are other options. Check the imports from the `PE` file and determine which one can be.

In my case, I found out it was `LoadStringW`, from `user32.dll`.

In `x86`, you will normally place a BP with a condition on some stack value. In `x64` this normally works differently ([x64 calling convention](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/x64-calling-convention?view=msvc-160)):

> By default, the x64 calling convention passes the first four arguments
> to a function in registers. The registers used for these arguments
> depend on the position and type of the argument. Remaining arguments
> get pushed on the stack in right-to-left order. Integer valued
> arguments in the leftmost four positions are passed in left-to-right
> order in RCX, RDX, R8, and R9, respectively...

According to the documentation [LoadStringW function](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-loadstringw):

```
int LoadStringW(
  HINSTANCE hInstance,
  UINT      uID,           // --> The identifier of the string to be loaded.
  LPWSTR    lpBuffer,
  int       cchBufferMax
);
```

Therefore, `uID` will be loaded in `EDX`. The right breakpoint for **x64dbg** is:

```
bp user32:LoadStringW;bpcnd user32:LoadStringW,EDX==66
```

Note: 102 is 66h

---

> 2- How could I detect this code in a disassembler such as Ghidra/IDA?

In Ghidra this is automatically managed. By looking into the `Defined Strings` you can find the strings in the resources:

```
                     pu_Error_140312196                              XREF[12]:
FUN_1400... (*) ,FUN_140...
   140312196 05004500...      p_unicode  u"Error"    Rsrc String ID 102
```

From here it is trivial to go to the references.